# Read data from unknown filesystem?

Tags: hard-drive, filesystems

I have a disk from an old XBMC live box which no longer mounts. I have plugged it into my ubuntu 12.10 computer, my macbook pro (usb) and my windows xp vm (macbook pro usb). They all see the disk but don't mount it.

Is there a program I can use to attempt to determine the filesystem and read the disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to use Partition Wizard http://www.partitionwizard.com/download.html to recover the partition table. Ended up being Ext3 (even though it was being reported as 0x42 which I believe to be something completely different).

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, you could run `fdisk -l /dev/sdX` (where sdX is your disk's name), that will list the partitions and their filesystems. So will `gparted`.

Any partitioning program should do this really on Linux or Windows or whatever.

Comment: nothing knew what it was- i think somehow the partition table was corrupt